# How to change only the beginning of value that matches condition?

Tags: sql, sql-server, replace

I have records from a specific table which contains fields: `phone1`, `phone2` .

How can i change value of `057` in these fields to
`053`, but only the beginning of the value?

*For example:* `057-4353009` should change to `053-4353009`, but `057-5405731` should change to `053-5405731` (*the second `057` in this specific number shouldn't change*).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to implement two parts:

1. Checking if the phone number starts with the specific sequence
   (`WHERE phone LIKE '057%'`)
2. Getting the part after `057` and
   concatenate with the new one (`'053' + RIGHT(phone, LEN(phone) - 3)`)

Here is the example query to do this:

```
UPDATE
  tbl
SET
  phone = '053' + RIGHT(phone, LEN(phone) - 3) -- Leaving the first 3 characters and use another one
WHERE
  phone LIKE '057%' -- Starts with 057
```

The general solution is something like this:

```
DECLARE
    @SearchString NVARCHAR(MAX) = '057'
  , @ReplaceString NVARCHAR(MAX) = '053'

UPDATE
  tbl
SET
  phone = @ReplaceString + RIGHT(phone, LEN(phone) - LEN(@SearchString))
WHERE
  phone LIKE (@SearchString + '%')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**REPLACE**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms186862.aspx) :

```
UPDATE tbl
SET phone = REPLACE(phone, '057-', '053-')
```

#### [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9201bb/1)

*Edit : In case you are not sure if the number has the structure with a delimiter like in **xxx–xxxxxxx**:*

```
UPDATE tbl 
SET phone = '053' + SUBSTRING(phone, 4 , LEN(phone) - 1)
WHERE LEFT(phone, 3) = '057';
```

#### [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7b0c8/3)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but if i have phone number
not wriiten with 057-, i mean, written like 0575405731 and not 057-5405731,
and i want to replace only the first 057 (the beginning).
How should i write it ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try this too (works for me):

```
UPDATE       table1
SET                phone = table2.leftc + table2.rightc
FROM            table1 INNER JOIN
                     (select  '053' as leftc, RIGHT(phone ,Len(phone) - 3)as rightc, phone 
                        from table1
                        where  LEFT(phone, 3) = '057') AS table2 ON table1.phone = table2.phone
```

[Working Demo Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/53776/4)

Answer (score 0):

for sql server 2012 use stuff

```
update tbl
set phone_number=stuff(phone_number,1,3,'053')
WHERE
  phone_number LIKE '057%'
```